# Runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2 * 2147483647 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++, runtime-error, runtime, unsigned, signed

I am trying to run the following code:

```
 int across(vector<int> &nums, int l , int m, int h){
 
        
        int i = l, j = m +1;
        int count = 0;
        unsigned long long int n;
        unsigned long long int prev;
        
        while(i <= m && j <=h){
            n = 2* nums[j];
            prev = nums[i];
            if(prev > n){
                count += m - i +1;
                j++;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    }
```

nums is a vector sorted from index l to m and from index m+1 to h.
I have to count number of pairs(i, j) such that `nums[i] > 2 * nums[j]`

I am getting runtime error when one of the element is 2147483647.

I tried using `long long int` and `unsigned long long int` but still shows the same.

Please help me get rid of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, the type of the left-hand side of an assignment (`=`) does not affect the type of right-hand side.

```
       n = 2* nums[j];
```

Here the expression is `2* nums[j]`, and since both `2` and `nums[j]` are of type `int`, the result is still of type `int`. The type of `n` plays no role.

Cast at least one of the arguments to `long long` to get a `long long` result:

```
       n = 2LL* nums[j];
```

Or

```
       n = 2* (long long) nums[j];
```